# How do you display a view controller from a universal link userActivity?

Tags: swift, ios-universal-links, nsuseractivity

**How can I present a view controller in my UserActionManager class from a userActivity?**

I am using Universal Links and have set up the apple-app-site-association file.

When I have found the userActivity.webPageURL.lastPathComponent equal to "registration" I would like to push to the RegistrationViewController.

Currently I've created a separate singleton called UserActionManager where I would like to handle lastPathComponents and present the correct View Controller.

In UserActionManager I can successful hit `handleRegistrationUserActivity` but need to add logic or a protocol to display the related ViewController.

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

        guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL, userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb else {
            return false
        }

        UserActionManager.shared.handleUserActivity(from: url)

        return true
 }
```

UserActionManager:

```
class UserActionManager {

    // MARK: - Singleton

    static let shared = UserActionManager()

    func handleUserActivity(from url: URL) {

        switch url.lastPathComponent {

        case "registration":
            handleRegistrationUserActivity()
        default:
            break
        }
    }

    private func handleRegistrationUserActivity() {

       // TODO: Set the root navigation controller to RegistrationViewController()
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: wanting to see what more I would need to add in UserActionManager to push to a specific view controller

Comment: Did you ever find the answer?